# angular material select module get event before open

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Currently I know of the event `openedChange` in the `<mat-select>` module. However this only fires *after* the panel already opens. I need a way of hooking into the module before the panel opens. I have tried using the click event handler instead, but it doesnt work when you click on the label, if the label is floating.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no such functionality at the moment. What exactly do you need to achieve? You might be able to do it in a different way

Comment: I've already found a way around this. But its kludgy and I don't like it. I want to change the options before the options are shown. But if I put the code to change the options list in the `openedChange` method the old options still show before the event is triggered and can change them. The kludgy way around this was to keep track of the open state with the `openChanged` event and compare it to the `panelOpen` property which seems to update right away. It requires a very unintuitive `if` condition. I would prefer a way to just update the options in an event before they are shown.

Comment: Hey, have you found a proper solution for this? Can you maybe show us your current one? Thank you!

Comment: @tris I made up a working example of what I did here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-deferred-loading?file=app%2Fselect-deferred-example.ts

Comment: Great idea! Like it! And thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what I want, I designed a deferred/async loading selection control.

See working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-deferred-loading?file=app%2Fselect-deferred-example.ts

Essentially I give the selection a temporary dummy option with a loading spinner while I go off and get the options I want, then I sub them into the select.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [autocomplete example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples). In that example, options are dynamically *filtered*, but for a select component you can use the same approach to dynamically *create* options.